# Git flow branches off stage

Tags: git, github, git-flow

My issue is that when I try to use git-flow it branches off stage, meaning my newest commits get ignored. What I try to do is

`git pull develop`

And make sure develop branch is up to date. Then I try to create a new feature branch

`git flow feature start branch`

However, the branch is clearly created off stage, because the files I just filled up with code and pushed into remote develop branch are empty again. If I switch back to develop branch, the code appears, but not in the newly created feature branch. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Did you took a latest pull of develop branch.
`git pull origin develop`
and then do git flow
`git flow feature start feature_branch`
See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow for more info.

Comment: Yes, I did. Nevermind, solved the problem, reinit of gitflow helped.